# How can I add more than one animation to the same model?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I am making a computer game character and have successfully added the first idle animation. When i add a keyframe after the idle animation to begin the run animation, Blender is causing unwanted bone movement in the first frames (it makes the legs move in the idle animation). How do i tell Blender that i do not want changes in following animations to be applied to the first?

Comment: You add keyframes for *everything* the reason why it causes moment is that some of the objects aren't keyframed

Comment: @ GiantCowFilms i am aware of this, i added a keyframe too for the second animation but its still causing unwanted bone movement in the first.

Comment: No to the first animation before you add the second animation, a holding keyframe

Comment: @ GiantCowFilms  how do i make a holding keyframe?

Comment: select all your bones that will be keyframed, insure they are in the correct position, go to the end of the action, and hit I select LocRotScale.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Shouldn't this be posted as an answer? Comments should be used for clarification, not answering.

Comment: @RayMairlot I did the comment answer again, sorry, I guess its when I'm not quite sure about my answer and more of a suggestion... I'll post it as an answer now I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add holding key frames to the end of you animation. At last frame it <kbd>A</kbd> to select all then <kbd>I</kbd>>*LocRotScale* to set the keyframes. now everything will stay in place

Comment: @ThomasGray If the answer solved your problem, could you please mark it as accepted [using the third button on the upper left hand corner](http://i.stack.imgur.com/E3ZSW.png) (feel free to use the one on the top too). This helps others know that the question as been answered sufficiently, and gives the answerer some more reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding this as an alternative approach for future. Blender has this thing called Actions that are essentially separated animation timelines. You can have any number of actions in your blend file for every animation you want to create (idle, idle2, walk, walk2...) and you can add, copy and delete them whichever way you like without them interfering with each other in any way.

You can then mix actions into longer animations (walk+hand wave) using the NLA editor, line them up as one long, continuous animation like you're doing now, or if you're targeting Unity or somesuch, FBX export can save all the actions along with the file. No need to manually set the frame ranges later.

You can get it done the way you're doing, sure. And actions are a bit confusing to work with first. But I think it's the easier route in the long run.