# Adding an idle animation to another one

Tags: animation

I have an animated character, I want to add subtle breathing/idle motion to it for more realism. Is it possible in Blender to make another animation for an armature, and "add" it to another animation?

Comment: does it help this thread? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26268/how-can-i-add-more-than-one-animation-to-the-same-model?rq=1

Comment: you can either duplicate the animation and change it the way you want, or create an action for only some bones and combine it with the others in the NLA Editor.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to create two actions set as "combine", it works!